# The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY, but debug window shows correct values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Hello guys I am new with asp.net mvc ANDcurrently working on my college project which is a college portal and using entity framework code first approach. However I am getting an error **

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_dbo.Notices_dbo.Colleges_CollegeId". The conflict occurred in
>   database "aspnet-QuickPly5-20180306011920", table "dbo.Colleges",
>   column 'Id'.

** 
I searched the whole web for solution everyone of them suggests that the value to be inserted should be present in primary table before entering data to the foreign key table. My model classes are as follows

**Collge.cs**

```
public class College
{

     public int Id { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Email { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Phone { get; set; }

     [Required]
     public string Address { get; set; }

}
```

**Notice.cs**

```
public class Notice {

        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public string ImagePath { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTime DatePosted { get; set; }

        //public bool IsPublic { get; set; }

        public College College { get; set; }

        public int CollegeId { get; set; }

    }
```

**NoticeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProcessForm(Notice notice, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + "-" + file.FileName;
                notice.ImagePath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/uploads/notice/" + fileName));

                file.SaveAs(notice.ImagePath);
            }

            if (notice.Id == 0)
            {
                notice.DatePosted = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Notice.Add(notice);
            }
            else
            {
                var noticeInDb = _context.Notice.Single(n => n.Id == notice.Id);

                notice.Title = noticeInDb.Title;
                notice.Description = noticeInDb.Description;
                notice.ImagePath = noticeInDb.ImagePath;
                //notice.IsPublic = noticeInDb.IsPublic;
            }

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return View("Index");
        }
```

**Table Definition**

**Notice**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Notices] (
    [Id]          INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Title]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Description] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [ImagePath]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [DatePosted]  DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [CollegeId]   INT            NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Notices] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Notices_dbo.Colleges_CollegeId] FOREIGN KEY ([CollegeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Colleges] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_CollegeId]
    ON [dbo].[Notices]([CollegeId] ASC);
```

**College**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Colleges] (
    [Id]      INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Email]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Phone]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    [Address] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Colleges] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

when i run the application normally i get the exception from the title but ***in the debug window when i checked it showed CollegeId = 1 (only have one row in the table) and NoticeId = 6 (have few notices already). I can correctly add data to the table manually without getting any error.***

I don't understand what i am doing wrong.

Thanks in advance.
(sorry for my English)

[Debug window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DAwj8.jpg)

Comment: In case of an existing _notice_ you are not updating the notice retrieved from the db, but you are updating the notice coming from the controller's parameters. This notice is not saved to the db.

Comment: Perhaps you are inserting a notice whose collegeId doesn't correspond with any Id from the College table?

Comment: You mean the else.. part, but it is saved in the database i guess

Comment: no Update method in _context.Notice

Comment: i just added the debug window screenshot

Comment: @Steve Yeah i see what you were talking about

Comment: As I thought, you need to set the CollegeId of the notice that you are inserting to something that exists as an Id of a College.

Comment: Not sure what you mean

Comment: Do you mean i should add annotation on top the CollegeId as foreign key?

Comment: table definition of notice.cs

Comment: CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Notices_dbo.Colleges_CollegeId] FOREIGN KEY ([CollegeId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Colleges] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE

Comment: I mean that CollegeID shouldn't be equal to 0. Instead it should be equal to something that already exists as a value in you Colleges column. For example, you have a College with Id = 1. Try to manually set notice.CollegeId = 1 and see if this work.

Comment: ok let me do that

Comment: Its working if i directly insert data to the notice table from Visual Studio LocalDb

Comment: So it works when you set the CollegeId?

Comment: Its working if i do this        <big>if (notice.Id == 0)
            {
                notice.DatePosted = DateTime.Now;
                notice.CollegeId = 1;
                _context.Notice.Add(notice);
            }</big>

Comment: yes but not when savechanges is called

Comment: @IndusDev I add my code to the answer, Can you check your view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem from view. I rewrite code. And It works following code.

CREATE VIEW:

```
@model stackoverflowquestion1.Models.Notice

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("ProcessForm", "Notice", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Notice</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ImagePath, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ImagePath, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatePosted, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePosted, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatePosted, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CollegeId, "CollegeId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBox("CollegeId", null, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CollegeId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And I changed code:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult ProcessForm(Notice notice, HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                var fileName = Guid.NewGuid() + "-" + file.FileName;
                notice.ImagePath = Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~/uploads/notice/" + fileName));

                file.SaveAs(notice.ImagePath);
            }

            if (notice.Id == 0)
            {
                //notice.DatePosted = DateTime.Now;
                _context.Notice.Add(notice);
            }
            else
            {

                _context.Entry(notice).State = EntityState.Modified;

                //var noticeInDb = _context.Notice.Single(n => n.Id == notice.Id);

                //notice.Title = noticeInDb.Title;
                //notice.Description = noticeInDb.Description;
                //notice.ImagePath = noticeInDb.ImagePath;
                //notice.IsPublic = noticeInDb.IsPublic;
            }
            //_context.Notice.Add(notice);

            _context.SaveChanges();

            return View("Index", _context.Notice);
        }
```

And Index controllers: Include methods set College property to Notice Model.

```
// GET: Notice
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = _context.Notice.Include(i => i.College);

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Man you really went too deep for answer

Comment: @IndusDev I am glad for it works. If you write your view code, I will check it.

Comment: Maybe you could briefly explain the essential difference to make your answer more accessible to future readers.

Comment: Ok @GertArnold I will as soon as edit my answer for details.

Comment: Ok I understood that the code now requires me to enter collegeid but still i would love it if all of this is happening in the background and i wouldn't have to add it myself

Comment: Though i like your idea

Comment: *i would love it if all of this is happening in the background* Ermmm, how would "the background" know which `CollegeId` should be set?

Comment: @GertArnold I Just got confused how the whole process works. my bad :-(

Answer (score 0):

Put in your College class and Notice class like this:

```
public class College
{
 //...

 public ICollection<Notice> Notice{ get; set; }

}

public class Notice
{
 //...

 [ForeignKey("College")]
 public int CollegeId { get; set; }
 public College College { get; set; }
}
```